# mac/windows cross platform login form design using fa icons( xamarian)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

hi Friends,
             how to design the form with fa icon in xamarian cross platform like i had shown in image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkzL3.png

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What isn't working?

Comment: tried with image tag but its not working